# cannot get background to fill with a minimum width

Tags: html, css, background

I am using CSS on a phpbb forum and I'm trying to get my background to fit.

The site is http://bofb.org if you want to see what it is doing.

Anyhow, I am trying to get the background to stretch the page but go a minimum width for differnt browser sizes.

I tried this:

```
body {
    /* Text-Sizing with ems: http://www.clagnut.com/blog/348/ */
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*font-size: 62.5%;          This sets the default font size to be equivalent to 10px */
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/bg_wrap.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

My image isn't showing at all with this. I got this from [this site](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

If I do this:

```
body {
    /* Text-Sizing with ems: http://www.clagnut.com/blog/348/ */
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*font-size: 62.5%;          This sets the default font size to be equivalent to 10px */
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background-image: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/bg_wrap.png");
   background-size:100%;
}
```

It shows up fine until you get a lower resolution screen or make the window smaller.

Ideally I'd like to have this at a specific width centered on the page and repeating but I've not gotten that to work either.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: look at my edit, im 100% sure thats the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work exactly like you want it. but u need to define a background-color so the background image doesnt get cut off on big screens.

```
background: url("./styles/reds/theme/images/bg_wrap.png") repeat-y center center fixed;
```

since you havent accepted my answer (which is correct)
here is the full style class for the body:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background: url("./styles/reds/theme/images/bg_wrap.png") repeat-y center center fixed; 
}
```

change the backgroud-color to remove white borders
and remove the html{ .. } css class plz. html tag is not supposed to be styled

Comment: I was trying to figure out why "./styles/reds/theme/images/bg_wrap.png" was ending up as "/styles/reds/theme/styles/reds/theme/images/bg_wrap.png". Apparently phpbb was converting it. I removed the . and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the **CSS** add

```
body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

Second try:

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    /* Text-Sizing with ems: http://www.clagnut.com/blog/348/ */
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    /*font-size: 62.5%;          This sets the default font size to be equivalent to 10px */
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background: url("{T_THEME_PATH}/images/bg_wrap.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Should I use any of the code that I've shown already?? My background doesn't line up with the forums with this...

Comment: The CSS-code for body was wrong, it must be 'background' not 'background-image' (I fixed that)

Answer (score 0):

The css you took from css-tricks is not copied correctly. Try using background:, not background-image:

Answer (score 0):

I had an image background in phpbb that wouldn't fit the whole screen.
I added width and height 100% to both the body and the html but it didn't fix it.
In the end I defined the background image to the html element as well, not just the body.
Seemed to do the trick.